# How do I express "I slept in a tent" in Japanese?

Tags: syntax, english-to-japanese

How do you say:

> I slept in a tent on/at the campsite.

I've been trying to make sense with it for a while now and I just can't make it work.

I think I know the vocabulary needed: 寝ました, テント, キャンプサイト and maybe 一張? If you know words that would fit better, please tell me.

Comment: Can you try to make a sentence yourself?

Comment: We are waiting for you to show your attempt first, before posting answers... I would use キャンプ[場]{じょう} rather than キャンプサイト, and wouldn't use 一張, btw...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I slept in a tent on/at the campsite.

You could say...

> - キャンプ[場]{じょう}で、テントで寝ました。
>     (*Lit.* slept in a tent, at the campsite.)
> - キャンプ場のテントで寝ました。 as suggested by @naruto.
>     (*lit.* slept in a tent of/at the campsite.)
> - キャンプに行って、テントで寝ました。
>     (*Lit.* went camping and slept in a tent.)

Comment: キャンプ場**の**テントで寝ました also works fine.

Comment: あ～なるへそ、確かに・・文字数足りず

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways you could say it.
テント+寝る seems fine if you want a short and easy way to say it.

As far as camping goes, you can use 野営 and 野宿 but I don't think they are as common as キャンピング.

If you want a fancy sentence, maybe you could go with something like.

> 昨日は野営して、テントで寝ました。

Which would mean

> Yesterday I went camping and slept in a tent.

Comment: 野宿て・・・ｗ　[野宿]{のじゅく} is quite different from キャンプ/[野営]{やえい}

Answer (score 1):

You could say:

> - キャンプ場にあるテントで寝ました。
>
>   - I slept in a tent (that is) standing on the(a) campsite.
> - キャンプ場のテントで寝ました。
>
>   - I slept in a tent of the campsite.

I rarely say キャンプサイト. It would be better if you said キャンプ場.